# When going back to the form from a PushRow table view scrolls up

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

When the form is long enough and you can scroll. If you have PushRow at the bottom and when tap on the PushRow new ViewController will be pushed. When going back or select an option the form scrolls up.
Any one has same problem? If yes can you share your solution for the problem. 
Thanks.